# authentication for cURL request to Azure storage

Tags: azure, curl, azure-storage

I'm finding the documentation on the Azure storage REST services a bit confusing.

How do I authenticate and consume an endpoint from Azure storage services over cURL?

I have:

- the url
- primary key
- secondary key

I just don't know what to do with them to make a proper request.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this documentation: [Authentication for the Azure Storage Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx), both primary key and secondary key can be used for authentication, you can choose any of them.